# Rose::DB masking in query statements

Tags: sql, perl, rose-db-object

I'm seeking some help on my Rose::DB issue as described below.

I have an account object, and this has an integer "accounttype" field. In this example I will use the following accounttype constants:

```
ACCOUNT_TYPE_SPECIAL_MASK   = 0x10;
ACCOUNT_TYPE_SPECIAL_1      = 0x10;
ACCOUNT_TYPE_SPECIAL_2      = 0x11;
ACCOUNT_TYPE_NORMAL_MASK    = 0x20;
ACCOUNT_TYPE_NORMAL_1       = 0x20;
ACCOUNT_TYPE_NORMAL_2       = 0x21;
```

At present, when I want accounts of a given type, I'd list them all and do something like this:

```
my $iter    = Test::Account::Manager->get_accounts_iterator(
    db              => $db,
    query           =>
    [
        'accounttype'   => [ ACCOUNT_TYPE_SPECIAL_1, ACCOUNT_TYPE_SPECIAL_2 ],
    ]
);
```

However, I'd like to be able to query for the accounts using the appropriate mask, rather than specify all possible types.

I'd like to be able to say:

```
my $iter    = Test::Account::Manager->get_accounts_iterator(
    db              => $db,
    query           =>
    [
        'accounttype'   => 'accounttype & ACCOUNT_TYPE_SPECIAL_MASK'
    ]
);
```

However, I haven't spotted any way to do this. Any help or recommendations most welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your SQL server understands the following:

```
(accounttype & 16) <> 0
```

[This](https://metacpan.org/pod/Rose::DB::Object::QueryBuilder) would then suggest that you could use the following:

```
[ \'(accounttype & ?) <> 0' => ACCOUNT_TYPE_SPECIAL_MASK ]
```

Under the circumstances, you could inline the constant.

```
\sprintf('(accounttype & %d) <> 0', ACCOUNT_TYPE_SPECIAL_MASK)
```

I don't know if these two versions result in different SQL, and I don't know which is faster if so.